# Redirecting domains to prevent duplicate content

Tags: duplicate-content, 301-redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

I have 2 domains:

```
www.company.com
```

and

```
www.product.com
```

I like both domains, they both point to the same site.  I have all my canonical links set up properly, but do I have to pick one of the domains to be the master?

Some of my visitors really like going to

```
product.com/page.html
```

And others like

```
company.com/page.html
```

But should they ALL 301 and redirect to

```
company.com/page.html?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they should all point to one domain. Not only is this good for SEO, but you can't forget about your human visitors. Having one domain is far less confusing then two.